# Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax success function that's executing the following code:

```
success: function(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.album.tracks.length; i++) {
      audio.push(json.album.tracks[i].url);
      var new_li = $('<li class="spacer" data-id="' + json.album.tracks[i].id + '">' + json.album.tracks[i].title + '</li>').hide();
      $('.playlistSongs').append( $(new_li).fadeIn(1000)); //1000 is just for testing    
  }
}
```

This works! The issue is its not working like I want it to. I want each track to fade in one at a time in the playlist div. However, all the tracks fade in together. I tried adding a .delay()  at different places but it made no difference.

My question is, what do I need to do in order to have each track fade in one at a time instead of all together? I also tried moving the code outside the success callback but still not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var lis = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < json.album.tracks.length; i++) {
      audio.push(json.album.tracks[i].url);
      lis += '<li class="spacer" data-id="' + json.album.tracks[i].id + '">' + json.album.tracks[i].title + '</li>';
  }

  $(lis)
        .hide()
        .appendTo('.playlistSongs')
        .each(function(index) {
            // For each li, wait some time and fadeIn. The first one will not have a delay
            $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
        });
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for the quick response, on a side note; Would know how to start each fadeIn before the prior fadeIn is complete(maybe at 50% completion)? To give the over all animation a more polished look. Thanks again.

Comment: Forget my last question, I got the staggered fadeIn effect by changing:
    $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);

to

    $(this).delay(400*index).fadeTo(1000, 1);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 $('.playlistSongs').append( $(new_li).fadeIn(1000));
```

try

```
$('.playlistSongs').append(new_li).fadeIn();
```